# How to check if user has left certain page

Tags: php

Right now, when the user comes to a page a session is started; that's working fine. But how can I detect when a user leaves that page? I need it so that when the user leaves the page, the session is destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use PHP to detect the user leaving the page, but you can send an ajax request via javascript on the unload event to destroy that users session.

Related post: [Can you fire an event in JavaScript before the user closes the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475302/can-you-fire-an-event-in-javascript-before-the-user-closes-the-window)

Comment: So partly solution is onbeforeunload ?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { /* ajax call to PHP script that destroys the session */};`

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to the others who posted, but i will wait little more, so i red that this function is not doing anything every time so it's not sure if it will work,

Comment: What do you mean? The link I provided above is just saying that the ajax will make the request, but that there will likely not be a response unless you set the ajax to a synchronous call.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only worried about pages within your website:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== 'page_with_session.php'){
    session_destroy(); // Kill session for all pages but page_with_session.php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is an asynchronous protocol. Asynchronous connections with user sessions are valid in a certain period of time. This time is also refered as expiry time. Therefore sessions have an expiry time. And this time will be renewed while a user accesses your page and invalidated(destroyed) if he does no action in this timeframe.

There is no other way to determine if a user leaves your page.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in general case

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how the internet works; you could try sending a signal with `onbeforeunload()` but it's not a guarantee.  Since session garbage is just a probability, and I don't know what your viewership looks like, I'd suggest putting something like this in a common file:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['last_seen']) && $_SESSION['last_seen'] < time() - 3600) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: logout_or_whatever.php');
    exit;
}
$_SESSION['last_seen'] = time();
```