# Check when user leaves page with PHP

Tags: php

Ok, I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696871/how-to-check-if-user-has-left-certain-page) and someone suggest using this code to check if user left page:

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== 'page_with_session.php'){
    session_destroy(); // Kill session for all pages but page_with_session.php
}
```

Now can someone please explain how REQUEST_URI works cause I can't seem to find it in the PHP manual, or can someone suggest another way to check when a user has left a page.

Please note **I can't use Javascript** for this project.

Comment: Well the concept of "leaving a page" is pretty wide. If I close my browser I left your page, but I'm sure you don't care about it the same way. Please provide some details :-)

Comment: I just want to unset a SESSION variable if the user goes to a link within the site

Comment: I see, but why would you do such thing? The session variable is used to store session informations, not ONLY login informations (just in case that was your objective to destroy login)

- sorry I don't mean to criticize, but just to understand a bit more

Comment: PHP only works upon request. So the browser needs to let PHP know when it leaves the page. There is no such browser-mechanism without javascript.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your answers, I guess I'll be learning Javascript next :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that code you can only tell when a user changes to another page on your server. If he leaves to another website, or closes the tab/browser, this won't work. Use javascript instead or use a session timeout.
REQUEST_URI is the URI of the current request, so if a user changes to another page on your server, you can check that it's not the "session page" and destroy the session. this will only work if you don't use rewrite or similar techniques.

Answer (score 1):

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.
>
> $HTTP_SERVER_VARS contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. (Note that $HTTP_SERVER_VARS and $_SERVER are different variables and that PHP handles them as such)
>
> 'REQUEST_URI'
> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

(c) php.net

As you see it's perfectly explained. When user leaves page you are not able to do what you want. So as @jimpic's told you use sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do this is to keep a really short session timeout, and then have either an embedded iframe with a meta refresh, or a javascript call out to your PHP page to keep it alive.