# How to determine how long a user has been on a certain page?

Tags: javascript, time, duration

I'm trying to figure out a way I can determine how long a user has been on a page. I'm open to javascript solutions that call some server script periodically, but I'm wondering if there are any better solutions than that?

I've read [Can you fire an event in JavaScript before the user closes the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475302/can-you-fire-an-event-in-javascript-before-the-user-closes-the-window) and it seems useful, but I need to know for certain when the page is closed.

Is there any way I can determine if the page is "active"? (meaning on top of other tabs / windows and the user is paying attention to it? this is for an educational web application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a javascript function which called a php script on the server periodically. Saved the 'last-updated' field in a database and set a minimum time before which it could be updated in order to ensure the polling function wasnt maliciously called by a user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this will be helpful.

However your problem seems more a browser task  then a page task.
If you want to implement a general, client side soltution you could write for example a chrome-extension.

In the `chrome.tabs.*` api there are all function needed to detect when a page is loaded, active, selected or is closed.

**onCreated**

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(Tab tab) {...}));
```

Fires when a tab is created.

**onRemoved**

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer tabId, object removeInfo) {...}));
```

Fires when a tab is closed.

**onSelectionChanged**

```
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(integer tabId, object selectInfo) {...}));
```

Fires when the selected tab in a window changes.

Comment: Very useful - I did not know that! But I think I'll need a different approach for handling it for all browsers...